# The difference for foreign key in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, database

I try changing the migration from integer to big integer and vice versa but the code still giving me error. This is the code for the foreign key:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('post_id');
            $table->biginteger('user_id')->unasigned()->index();         
            $table->biginteger('company_id')->unasigned()->index();          
            $table->biginteger('job_id')->unasigned()->index();          
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('posts', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('company_id')->on('companies');
             $table->foreign('job_id')->references('job_id')->on('jobs');
        });
    }
```

This is the code for the user:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->foreignid('companyid');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->string('CV');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Then I change it to foreignid and there is no error so I want to know what is the different or the correct way to call the foreign key from a table to the other?

Comment: Please share the error message too

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos and errors.

1. `foreignid` should be [`foreignId`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId)
2. use [`unsigned`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-modifiers) instead of `unasigned`

---

for the `post` you can use

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('post_id');
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
    $table->foreignId('company_id')->constrained('companies');
    $table->foreignId('job_id')->constrained('jobs');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

for the `users` you can use

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id('user_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->foreignId('company_id')->constrained('companies');
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('CV');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> **Note**: Make sure `companies` tabled created before the `users` and `posts` table

Comment: if i use constraint for the companies it will refer to the id column when the column already got named as company id so what should i do?

Comment: Do you mean in `companies` table you don't have column id? Post the company table migration

Comment: ```   
{
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('company_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```
the companies id is named company_id

Comment: add field call `->references('company_id')`

Comment: Like this `$table->foreign('company_id')->references('company_id')->on('companies');`